# Rails moving from 2.2.2 to 2.3.8 - rake not loading the environment same as the console or my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, rake, environment

I have an app that has been around a while that I'm migrating for
Rails 2.3.8.  There have been a lot of interesting issues, but I'm on
the home stretch, but have now run into some very odd errors.

The gist is when I run a task with rake it fails, but when I run the
same code form the console it works fine.  The 'fix' I devised was to
move my include ModuleNameA, include ModuleNameB, etc to the bottom of
the AR file.

I don't like this 'fix' as I don't understand it.  Before I moved them
the AR object (we will call it Bob) kept throwing undefined method
errors when it was called through the rake invocation.  It was invoked
in the rake task, but in another AR object.

So the rake task was running something like Worker.work, and it would
fail as described above.  When I run Worker.work from the console it
would pass.  Once I moved the includes to the bottom of the file both
would work.

Anyone ever seen anything like this?  I feel like something
fundamental isn't correct.   Like I have broken something basic to the
functionality and my 'fix' is some kind of weird patch.

thanks.
Erik

PS:

There is a module that I'm including in my AR object.  It adds class and instance methods by doing:

```
def self.included(base)
  base.extend(ClassMethods)
end
```

All of the methods in this module are available in the console, but not through rake tasks.

Update:
I noticed that if i take the :work => :environment part out of the
rake task and instead in the task do block require the environment
file by hand (e.g. require(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'config',
'environment'))) it works fine.  All of a sudden all of my class
methods are available.  this is very disturbing.

Comment: Maybe you or something else has overriden the `environment` task?

Comment: no, i found it and put a puts in it and it's calling the one in railties.  I put a puts statement in misc.rake and it's calling it there.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out....

We had a directory under app/models called deals that was not included in the load path.  That is where my module was that was giving me all the issues.  Why it was being loaded OK from the console and not with rake...I don't know.

Once I added this to the config.load_path everything has started working fine.  I never noticed this because in 2.2.2 everything worked fine, the app in production or dev mode, the console and the rake tasks in dev, test, and production mode.

I figured it was something just basic i was doing wrong as the error was obtuse and my 'fixes' looked like really bad ideas.